# Code crashes when running but not when debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, crash

I should program a sort of scrabble game but I have a big issue. I should extract a card for each player that contains a letter in order to decide who starts the game. Then, I must put again the card in the bag. However when I run the program, it crashes, but when I use the debug it works. Can someone help me please?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

char letterarand(char *firstelementarray, int numelement, vector<int> &pos)
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int n = rand() % 100;  // 0 - 99
  pos.push_back(n);
  if (firstelementarray[n] == '0') {
    pos.pop_back();
    letterarand(firstelementarray, numelement, pos);
  }
  return firstelementarray[n];
}

void order(vector<char> &letters, vector<string> &name, int num, vector<int> &positions)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    cout << letters[i] << endl;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; ++i) {
    for (int j = i; j < num; ++j) {
      if (letters[i] > letters[j]) {
        char temp = letters[i];
        letters[i] = letters[j];
        letters[j] = temp;
        string swap = name[i];  
        name[i] = name[j];
        name[j] = swap;
        int temp2 = positions[i];  
        positions[i] = positions[j];
        positions[j] = temp2;
      }
    }
  }
}

void insert(char *firstelementarray, int numplayers,
                 vector<int> positions, vector<char> extract)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < numplayers; ++i) {
    cout << extract[i] << " " << positions[i] << endl;
  }
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numplayers; ++i) {  //letters extracted are trasformed in '0'
    firstelementarray[positions[i]] = extract[j];
    ++j;
  }
}

int main()
{
  cout << "                  UPWORDS:               "
       << endl;
  cout << endl;
  char c = '0';
  vector<string> players;
  string playersname;
  cout << "Number of player (2-4):" << endl;
  cin >> c;
  while ((!(c >= '2' && c <= '4'))) {
    cin >> c;
  }
  int playersnum = c - '0';
  vector<char> extract;
  char bag[100] = {
      'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D',
      'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'F',
      'G', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'J', 'K',
      'K', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N',
      'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'R', 'R',
      'R', 'R', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'U', 'U',
      'U', 'U', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z'};
  vector<int> positions;
  cout << "name players: " << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < playersnum; ++i) {
    cout << "player " << i + 1 << " :";
    cin >> playersname;
    players.push_back(playersname);
    extract.push_back(letterarand(bag, 100, positions));
    bag[positions[i]] = '0';
  }
  order(extract, players, playersnum, positions);
  insert(bag, playersnum, positions, extract);
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the **shortest** code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: You need to say what input you use when the program crashes.

Comment: Try to run valgrind, it will propaly say, where your error is. Also please, indent your code properly, how are we supposed to read through it, when we have to hop between indention-levels all the time :(

Comment: Probably out of bounds vector access. Use `.at` rather than `[]`, which will give you a runtime error.

Comment: Hint:  use `std::swap`.

Comment: @Bathsheba I tried but it doesn't change

Comment: You should return the result of the recursive call: `return letterarand(primoelementoarray, numelementi, pos);`

Comment: Any compiler warnings?  They are hints of where something suspicion is happening.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it continues to crash

Comment: Hello Alessia, the game is not crashing with UB it is just stopping at some point after the card draw with the values to determine who start.

Comment: @ravenspoint it crashes when I insert the name of the players (usually the second or the third), but it doesn't happen everytime

Comment: The problem is most likely reading some uninitialized memory. In debug mode it will be zero'd out, but in release it will contain a garbage value.

Comment: @HasanPatel so what should I do?

Comment: @MaxLanghof what shoud I initialize?

Comment: You should make sure that every variable you use is initialized before you read from it. By the way, it would also really help to have the code in English if you are asking for help on an English site, as most people won't be able to make sense of the variable and function names otherwise.

Comment: Unrelated: You only want to call `srand` once except in very unusual circumstances. Every time you call it you restart the random number generator, and you almost never want to do that. Place the call to `srand` somewhere near the top of `main` and remove all other calls.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I transleted it in english, sorry, you were right. However I can't find anything that should be initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In letterand the recursive code is hard to understand.  May I suggest:

```
char letterarand(char *firstelementarray, int numelement, vector<int> &pos)
{
  srand(time(NULL));        // should only be done once!  Move to main

  // chose random letter, not previously chosen
  int n
  do {
       n = rand() % 100;  // 0 - 99
  } while( firstelementarray[n] == '0';
  char letter = firstelementarray[n];

  // mark letter as chosen
  firstelementarray[n] = '0';

  pos.push_back(n);
  return letter;
}
```

Comment: what does it change when adding (numgiocatori)?

Comment: Constructs vector of required length containing default values http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Comment: I tried it but, as before, it works only during the debug

Comment: I realized now that the vector "position" is not empty when I want to assign '0' because in the first function (letterand) there is a pushback

Comment: why? It may be true when the same card is extracted for the second time. In fact the element that corresponds to the card, assumes the value '0'